# What's the cheapest way to get a Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition license?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I know I can purchase it for $299.00, but my primary reason for upgrading from the Express version is I want to be able to use ReSharper, which is an additional expense. Are there any ways I can get a VS copy for less than off-the-shelf price? Any special programs I can join, or is there a special "developer" version :) (kind of redundant, I know)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Microsoft currently has time limited action where it is possible to buy the Visual Studio 2008 (both Standard and Pro) at upgrade price ($199 for standard) even when upgrading from the Express editions or even free tools such as Eclipse. See the section "Before you buy" on [this page](http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/Visual-Studio-2008-Standard-Edition-Upgrade/product/99E69042). However it is possible that this is limited to some regions.

Answer (score 3):

You can get all the MS dev tools and lots of other goodies for about that much if you join their [empower](http://www.empowerforisv.com/) program or free with [bizspark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/)

Comment: Empower licences are only valid for max 2 years and you hace to pay annual fee of about 300 USD.

Comment: Thanks - the rules/promotions/options change periodically

Answer (score 3):

https://downloads.channel8.msdn.com/ - Free MS Dev stuff for students.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a .NET User Group in your community? If so, contact them. Often they can get things at a discount. MS User Group Support Services provides plenty of freebies for user groups, perhaps they have a copy you can have.

Comment: +1 My local user group typically has prizes of Visual Studio Pro licenses (courtesy of Microsoft). Not sure about discounts but maybe if you're lucky you'll get one for free. :)

Answer (score 2):

No idea if you qualify, but if you're a student, I believe you can get it for free.  If you're not, get your company to pony up :)

Edit: Here's the [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx) site, for students.

Comment: Yes but that would be the academic version and that's probably only valid as long as you're a student (or a teacher) and is limited to non-commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

Just something out of left field here...
Why not also look at SharpDevelop, it's surprisingly good, it's free and you have access to the source code for it. I'm not sure if ReSharper supports it, probably not, but there is already some good refactoring stuff in there, plus of course you can extend it yourself. IMO its worth a look at least.

http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Features.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My university had an MSDNAA subscription for CompSci majors which gave me student licenses to practically every Microsoft product on the market... but it wasn't really advertised. I'm not sure how you'd go about finding if your school does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Got to any one of the dozens Microsoft conferences held all the time. The fumble over themselves to give you free copies of stuff - including Visual Studio.